# mean stack application runtime error in the webstorm ide

Tags: mean-stack

I am running my mean stack application using webstorm ide. when i trying to run the application, i am getting the following error

```
Error: ENOENT, open 'C:\Documents and Settings\ssit\WebstormProjects\ts\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\node_modules\public\favicon.ico'
```

could you please explain me the cause of the problem and tell me the possible solution.

Comment: This just means that it's not finding the favicon.
It's not a critical bug - I need to check if we still provide a default favicon in the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have faced same problem. once i have changed the node server path at run which is at the top right corner. It solved my problem. Hope it may solve yours.